# Restore Database in SQL Server 2014 with different name

Tags: sql-server, restore, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL Server 2014.
I have a database but as the user deleted some records, I need to create another database with a different name 
and then transfer the data from the restored database to the current one.

I know I need to rename the restored database.

From my understanding, I also need to go to the Files page and then click on Relocate all files to folder.

In terms of renaming, do I need to rename both the Data file folder and the Log file folder?

Any assistance would help clarify

Comment: If you are placing the database in the same folder as the previous database you can just rename the physical files.

Comment: This link might do help you: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa176752(v=sql.80).aspx its for SQL Server 2000 but might work for SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 2):

Perform a `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` first, so you understand the logical and physical names of the files.

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'c:\temp\foo.bak';
```

From there, you just need to fill in the pertinent pieces here:

```
RESTORE DATABASE foo_copy FROM DISK = 'c:\temp\foo.bak'
  WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY,
  MOVE N'foo_data' TO 'c:\...\foo_copy.mdf',
  MOVE N'foo_log' TO 'c:\...\foo_copy.ldf';
```

In case it isn't clear: don't use the UI for this. Pointing and clicking is not something you can easily reproduce, document, or store in source control. It can be a useful way to generate the commands in some cases (using the handy <kbd>Script</kbd> button), but in the long run you're much better off knowing the commands the UI would have generated anyway.